# Data Oriented Design with Mike Acton - Are 'loops per cache line' calculations right?

Tags: caching, data-oriented-design

I've watched Mike Acton's talks about DOD a few times now to better understand it (it is not an easy subject to me). I'm referring to  [CppCon 2014: Mike Acton "Data-Oriented Design and C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc)
 and [GDC 2015: How to Write Code the Compiler Can Actually Optimize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x61H6qEtK08).

But in both talks he presents some calculations that I'm confused with:
[image: Mike Acton's calculations]

This shows that **FooUpdateIn** takes 12 bytes, but if you stack 32 of them you will get 6 fully packed cache lines. Same goes for **FooUpdateOut**, it takes 4 bytes and 32 of them gives you 2 fully packed cache lines.

In the **UpdateFoos** function, you can do ~5.33 loops per each cache line (assuming that **count** is indeed 32), then he proceeds by assuming that all the math done takes about 40 cycles which means that each cache line would take about 213.33 cycles.

Now here's where I'm confused, isn't he forgetting about reads and writes? Even though he has 2 fully packed data structures they are in different memory spaces.
In my head this is what's happening:

1. Read **in[0].m_Velocity[0]** (which would take about 200 cycles based on his previous slides)
2. Since **in[0].m_Velocity[1]** and **in[0].m_Foo** are in the same cache line as **in[0].m_Velocity[0]** their access is free
3. Do all the calculation
4. Write the result to **out[0].m_Foo** - Here is what I don't know what happens, I assume that it would discard the previous cache line (fetched in 1.) and load the new one to write the result
5. Read **in[1].m_Velocity[0]** which would discard again another cache line (fetched in 4.) (which would take again about 200 cycles)
6. ...

So jumping from **in** and **out** the calculations goes from **~5.33 loops/cache line** to **0.5 loops/cache line** which would do 20 cycles per cache line.

Could someone explain why wasn't he concerned about reads/writes? Or what is wrong in my thinking?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find an answer. I'm very confused as well. Also I got the impression that he said the memory fetch and sqrt operations will happen concurrently. However, isn't the process just sequential and the processor just stall when the memory fetch is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not got the answer. As about the fetch happening concurrently I think what happens is that on the first iteration in can't be concurrent (since you don't have the data for sqrt operation), but after you receive the first line of cache it will start operate on those values and at the same time it will fetch another cache line. Though I'm not sure. I would love to speak with him front to front lol, I have so many questions...

Answer (score 0):

If we assume L1 cache is 64KB and one cache line is 64 bytes then there are total 1000 cache lines. So, in step 4 write to the result out[0].m_Foo will not discard the data cache in step 2 as they both are in different memory locations. This is the reason why he is using separate structure for updating out m_Foo instead directly mutating it in inplace like in his first implementation. He is just talking till point of calculation value. Updating value/writing value will have same cost as in his first implementation. Also, processor can optimize loops quite well as it can do multiple calculations in parallel(not sequential as result of first loop and second loop are not dependent). I hope this helps

Comment: *1024 cache lines